# Make http calls in batches

Tags: java, batch-processing

I have this mainFunction which makes call to a method delete() which calls an external endpoint using http client, this takes multiple ids at once to perform operations on all ids, for my case these ids can be upto 3000 and I want to make these calls happen in batches of 100 or so, so that the system doesnt timeout in a single go waiting for operation to complete for all 3000 ids

What is the best suggested way of acheieving this, so that the call to delete() itself from mainFunction happens in batches

```
    public void mainFunction() {
    .
    .
    .
    //delete call to be made in batches
    deleteCall(listOfIds);
    .
    .
    .
  }

  public void deleteCall(List<> listOfIds) {
  RestTemplate template = HttpUtils.getRestTemplate();
  //listOfIds is an ArrayList of 3000 ids
  String ids = StringUtils.join(listOfIds, ',');
  String url = BaseUrl + "/api/delete?Ids=" + ids;
  HttpHeaders httpHeader = getHttpHeaders();
  HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(httpHeader);
  try {
        ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> response = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
            ResponseDTO.class);
    }catch(Exception e) {
       Log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make 3000 parallelized calls to the delete API or are you asking how to make a single call to the delete API with 3000 IDs? The first can be done by using an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and calling [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). The second depends on whether the API supports batch deletes.

Comment: @kingkupps Not sure the about first doesnt server the purpose, looking for making delete call in batches of 100, 30 times calling delete method in a simple way I'd say

Comment: In that case, whether you can do this or not is dependent on the implementation of the API you are using. If this is an API you own or can update, then you should make changes there and accept the IDs you want to delete in the request body. If this is not an API you own, can you share the documentation for it?

Comment: @kingkupps if i change this api to get ids in request body then also i wont be wanting to get 3000ids together, how do you suggest that then?

Comment: Assuming you use something like UUID for IDs (which would be on the larger side) you're looking at 36 bytes per ID and 108KB for 3000 IDs. That's not very big but if you want you could always break it down further if you need to (i.e. send 3 requests with 1000 IDs or 6 with 500, etc.). If you use a smaller ID format you shouldn't have any issues sending 3000 IDs at once.